# Solution of Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, chinese-remainder-theorem

The question is

> Given that, x ≡ 6 (mod 11), x ≡ 13 (mod 16), x ≡ 9 (mod 21), x ≡ 19 (mod 25). Find x.

Using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm I computed the modular inverse `M1^-1 = 8, M2^-1 = 15, M3^-1 = 2 and M4^-1 = 6`. Now putting all the values in the formula, I get `x = (a1 M1 M1^-1 + a2 M2 M2^-1 + a3 M3 M3^-1 +  a4 M4 M4^-1) (mod M) = (6×8400×8 + 13×5775×15 + 9×4400×2 + 19×3696×6 ) mod (92400) = 2029869 (mod 92400) = 89469`.
Am I did the correct calculation?

Comment: One nice thing about problems like this...it's a lot easier to *check* an answer than it is to find it in the first place.

Comment: @lulu The answer to this question is given in the book is 89469 (mod 92400). That's why I am a little be confused

Comment: @Moo other online calculators eg. https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/chinese-remainder gives the result 89469 (mod 92400)

Comment: Yes...and that's the answer you got, right?  I don't see the problem.

Comment: @lulu Which one is correct 89469 or 89469(mod 92400) ?. Although 89469(mod 92400) is equal to 89469

Comment: Right, and that's the answer you got, no?  Don't forget, solutions to problems like this are only defined modulo the least common multiple of the moduli.  Is that the point that's confusing you?

Comment: The solution is any integer of the form $89469+92400\times k$ for some integer $k$.   Again, note that $92400=\text {lcm}(11,16,21,25)$.

Comment: For instance, the general solution to "$n\equiv 1 \pmod 2$ and $n\equiv 2\pmod 3$" is not $5$ but rather the set of integers of the form $5+6k$.  For instance, $11$ works just as well as $5$.